# java - selenium - I can get text of element but can't click its link

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am having trouble clicking on a link in a webpage using the selenium webdriver in firefox.

Here is a snippet of my code regarding the issue:

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.id("AccNumSpan" + i));
                if(option.getText().contains("48494")){ 
                    List <WebElement> listOfOptions1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='row" + i +"']/td[10]/nobr"));
                    for(WebElement option1 : listOfOptions1){
                        System.out.println(option1.getText());

                        String id = option1.getAttribute("id");
                        System.out.println(id);
                        option1.click();
}
```

Here is the html of the link that I am trying to click:

```
<td class="cell" align="left">
<nobr>
<span id="link15796367" class="stmtListTableLinkDocument" onclick="billDocsClient.ShowDocTypeList(event, 'table#StatementTable', 'span#link15796367', 908244, 15796367, '6728_22198', '48494 (Merrill Lynch Europe PLC)', '6/1/2014', '34969691/175474');" onmouseout="this.className='stmtListTableLinkDocument'" onmouseover="this.className='docLink'">View Monthly Invoices</span>
</nobr>
</td>
```

When I run the code, it prints "View Monthly Statement" from option1.getText ( so it does find the element), but when I try option1.click() (which is what I want to do) nothing happens except the text gets underlined or whatever but the link isn't opened. Also, it does not print anything for option1.getAttribute("id") or for any attribute using .getAttribute

Any way to get around this? All help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean getText() is printing `View Monthly Invoices`? Also, can you show more of the html so we can see the element with id `AccNumSpan`?

Comment: SiKing provided a fix, thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking on the span element below your nobr:

```
option1.findElement(By.xpath("span")).click();
```

as that seems to be the clickable element.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I shall name my first born child after you SiKing

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Monthly Invoices")).click()
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the qusetion, code only answers are not high quality.  A better answer would explain what the code does, tell where to insert it, explain why this approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: insert it at place of option1.click(); It will find link with text "View Monthly Invoices" and then perform click operation.

Comment: That's basically what I was doing. It didnt actually click the link just clicked the text. SiKing provided the fix; thanks for your input though