# Clicking on text contained in span and div

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

This is the HTML code.

```
<div class="help-service-content">
<div class="help-content">
<a name="61AC9B9656AE"></a>
<h1>Help Contents</h1>
<div>    
<div id="9F38FD">
<a name="9F38FD"></a>
</div>
<h2>
<span><a href="/register.html">Register</a></span>
</h2> 
<div id="20D4FF">
<a name="20D4FF"></a>
</div>
<h2>
<span><a href="/subscribe.html">Subscribe</a></span>
</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to click on "Register" text using Appium on my android mobile app, but all it ends up doing is underlining the text. And the link doesn't open up. This is similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273792/java-selenium-i-can-get-text-of-element-but-cant-click-its-link). So, I tried the following and that didn't work either.

```
WebElement element = DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().findElement(By.xpath("span"));
element.click();
```

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the `a` element (not `span`) *by link text*:

```
DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().findElement(By.linkText("Register"));
```

Or, `by xpath`:

```
DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span/a[. = 'Register']"));
```

Comment: I tried that and Appium threw an error saying "Invalid locator strategy: link text". I am running Appium version 1.3.5.

Comment: The update didn't work as well. I use android.webkit.webview to render the HTML in my mobile app. When I ran the code, Appium returned saying that "Could not find an element using supplied strategy.". However, I thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Indrajeet, just to make sure, are you doing that within web context?

Comment: @KirillZhukov How do you specify a context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to web context in order to work with WebViews.

To get current context:

```
DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().getContext();
```

To get available contexts

```
DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().getContextHandles();
```

Suppose you have available `"WEBVIEW_0"` context. To switch to this context:

```
DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().context("WEBVIEW_0");
```

After that you are able to work with WebView of this context.

**Source:** http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#available-contexts

**Note:** on iOS you **have** to run `ios_webkit_debug_proxy_server` with port `27753`. You can run it from Appium source code:  https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/bin/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js
or as standalone utility: https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Comment: I ran getContextHandles() to get a list of available contexts. One of them is the webview. However, the Java program fails when I try to switch to Webview context.

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: logger.info("Show available contexts "+DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().getContextHandles()); logger.info("Show default context "+DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().getContext()); DeviceWrapper.getAppiumDriver().context("WEBVIEW_com.example.sample.webviewapp")​; 

I have created a dummy Android webview app.

Comment: It definitely should work if you have WebView with this context... Could you provide more details? Maybe more Appium logs. Are you working on real device or emulator?

Comment: I am working with two devices, one with Android 4.x and another with Android 5.0. The test that I am carrying out passes on Android 4.x device but fails on the Android 5.0. Nothing has changed, the HTML code that is rendered in the webview hasn't changed. I use Appium for the framework.

Comment: The only thing that has changed is the android.webkit.webview from Android 4.x to Android 5.0. When working with a Android 4.x device, I was able to select hyperlinks shown in the webview in Appium Inspector and was able to "tap" on them. [Appium Inspector lets you tap, swipe, and perform other actions on web elements]. However, when I connect a Android 5.0 device, Appium Inspector is not able to tap through the links.

Comment: Speaking about contexts, Appium Inspector does offer a dropdown of available contexts to choose from. On Android 4.x device, taps on links work without having to choose Webview context. On Android 5.0 device, taps on link do not work on all contexts including Webview context.

Comment: What does getPageSource() function return on Android 5? Do you see your elements there?

Comment: getPageSource() function does return all elements when code is run on both devices (one with Android 4.x and another with 5.0)

Comment: I must say, that the xpath differ for the links. On the device running Android 5.0, the xpath for the first link is //android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[1]. On the device running Android 4.x, it is //android.webkit.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[1]